# Does the smooth embedding $[0,1)\times \partial M \to M$ diffeomorphic onto its image？

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary, assume there exist a smooth embedding $[0,1)\times \partial M \to M$,can we claim it diffeomorphic onto it's image?(Where the map given above is the collar neiborhood for manifold with boundary)

I prove it as follows: First both side are smooth manifold with same dimension,which means that the smooth immersion map(in particular smooth embedding map) is in fact local diffeomorphism (By proporsition 4.8 in Lee's smooth manifold),since this local diffeomorphism is bijective onto it's image so it's diffeomorphism.Is my proof correct?The problem here is the proporsition for rank thoerem seems hold for smooth manifold without boundary so I'm not sure my proof is correct?

Comment: Tell me your definition of "embedding". Usually, embeddings are diffeomorphisms onto their image by definition.

Comment: @Thorgott embedding here means smooth immersion + topological embedding

Comment: @yili then by the inverse function theorem, your definition impies that an embedding is a diffeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: @Didier thank you I will think it more carefully later,the idea is similar